# Finding an English version of Hjortnaes' paper on the series representation of $\zeta(3)$

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta

Hjortnaes published a paper in 1953 establishing the following series representation for $\zeta(3)$, where $\zeta$ is the Riemann Zeta function:

$$
{\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\zeta (3)&={\frac {5}{2}}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{k-1}{\frac {k!^{2}}{(2k)!k^{3}}}\\&={\frac {5}{2}}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{{\binom {2k}{k}}k^{3}}}\end{aligned}}}
$$

The paper is entitled "*Overføring av rekken ${\displaystyle \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\left({\frac {1}{k^{3}}}\right)}$  til et bestemt integral*", and appeared in the Scandinavian Mathematical Society's *Proc. 12th Scandinavian Mathematical Congress*. Unfortunately the paper is in Norwegian, which I do not understand. A (quick) Google search did not yield any English translations for this paper. Does anyone know where I can find one?

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no English version of that paper. Just in case you are more interested in the formula itself, you can look for Roger Apery's paper instead.

Comment: Wikipedia [Apéry's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry's_constant) writes that Markov found the proof before Hjortnæs. This is their reference: _Markov, A. A. (1890), "Mémoire sur la transformation des séries peu convergentes en séries très convergentes", Mém. De l'Acad. Imp. Sci. De St. Pétersbourg, t. XXXVII, No. 9: 18pp._

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That is highly interesting, I have not heard of that before. Do you have a link? I could not find it anywhere.

Comment: I think this link works: [https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/46874381](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/46874381)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Amazing, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no English translation of Hjortnaes' paper. Moreover, after hours of searching I was not able to find Apéry's original paper proving the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$.

However, the following papers give various different proofs of the above identity:

- [Lemma 3.1.3 in this paper](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~chaubey2/snehathesis.pdf)
- [Page 5 in this paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20110706114957/http://www.maths.mq.edu.au/~alf/45.pdf)
- [A proof by Apéry in this small note](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/file.php?17,file=55546,filename=Apery.pdf)
- [Van der Poorten's excellent paper, section 3.](http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf)